# Why the volume folder is empty after a redis save?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

### Code

I'm trying to run a redis service defined inside a `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:5-alpine"
    volumes:
      - ./redis-vol:/home/data 
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/
```

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine3.8
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN apk add python2-dev build-base linux-headers pcre-dev && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
# Source files
COPY ./api.py . 
COPY ./conf.ini .
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "conf.ini"]
```

The app consists of this snippet running a `uwsgi` interface on port `8080`

```
import uwsgi
import redis
r = redis.Redis('redis')
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    r.append('hello', 'world!')
    r.save()
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

And this is the conf.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8080 
wsgi-file = api.py 
master = true
process = 2
enable-threads = true
uid = 1001
gid = 1001
```

The app service is supposed to save a `key:value` pair through redis every time it receives a request to `http://localhost:8080`.
Upon a successful request, the docker-compose process returns the following log:

```
redis_1_bdf757fbb2bf | 1:M 26 Nov 2018 15:38:20.399 * DB saved on disk
app_1_5f729e6bcd36   | [pid: 17|app: 0|req: 1/1] 172.21.0.1 () {38 vars in 690 bytes} [Mon Nov 26 15:38:20 2018] GET / => generated 11 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
redis_1_bdf757fbb2bf | 1:M 26 Nov 2018 15:38:20.998 * DB saved on disk
app_1_5f729e6bcd36   | [pid: 17|app: 0|req: 2/2] 172.21.0.1 () {40 vars in 691 bytes} [Mon Nov 26 15:38:20 2018] GET /favicon.ico => generated 11 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

### Problem

Despite the `DB saved on disk` log, the `redis_vol` folder is empty and the dump.rdb file doesn't seem to be saved anywhere else.

What I am doing wrong? I've also tried to use `redis:alpine` as image but I have the following error at startup:

```
redis_1_bdf757fbb2bf | 1:M 26 Nov 14:57:27.003 # Can't handle RDB format version 9
redis_1_bdf757fbb2bf | 1:M 26 Nov 14:57:27.003 # Fatal error loading the DB: Invalid argument. Exiting.
```

And I've also tried to map the dump.rdb in the redis service as follows:

```
  redis:
    image: "redis:5-alpine"
    volumes:
      - ./redis-vol/dump.rdb:/home/data/dump.rdb
```

but the docker creates a folder named **`dump.rdb/`** instead of a readable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to the redis documentation on the [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) page

> If persistence is enabled, data is stored in the VOLUME /data

So you are using the wrong volume path. Yout should use `/data` instead

```
volumes:
    - ./redis-vol:/data
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still face the problem even after changing the volume map to
`<your-volume>:/data`

Make sure to delete the previous container with
`docker container prune`
before restarting your container again

Answer (score 0):

To be able to mount a single file for your container with docker-compose, use absolute path of the file you want to mount from your filesystem:

```
  redis:
    image: "redis:5-alpine"
    volumes:
      - /Users/username/dirname/redis-vol/dump.rdb:/home/data/dump.rdb
```

Answer (score 0):

As [codestation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160992/codestation) correctly pointed out, it is on the
[official documenation](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) but he is suggesting
[mount point](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) instead of [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) which has some additional cons.
In both cases in documentation there is also statement about "persistence
enabled":
`$ docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes`
or in your docker-compose file:

```yaml
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        command: redis-server --appendonly yes 
        volumes:
            - your-volume:/data
```